# Lipschitz Continuous Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let f : R → R be a polynomial of degree d ≥ 2. Show that f is not Lipschitz continuous. Where exactly should I begin with this problem?

Answer (score 5):

If it were Lipchitz continuous, it would have a bounded derivative, as it is differentiable.

> **THM** Suppose $f:A\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable on $A$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous $\iff$ $f'$ is bounded on $A$.

**P** Suppose $f'$ is bounded. Let $M=\sup \{f'(x):x\in A \}$. Then, by the mean value theorem, $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|$$ for $x,y\in A$. Now assume $f'$ is unbounded on $A$. Then for any $K>0$ we can pick $\xi\in A$ such that $|f'(\xi)|>K$.  Let $\{\xi_n\}$ be a sequence of points in $A$ converging to $\xi$, but different from it. Since $$\left|\frac{f(\xi)-f(\xi_n)}{\xi-\xi_n}\right|\to f'(\xi)$$

there must exist $N>0$ such that $$\left|\frac{f(\xi)-f(\xi_N)}{\xi-\xi_N}\right|>\frac K2$$

and $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: beatiful argument!

Comment: Just a little nitpick: If you only assume $f$ differentiable, $f'(x_0)>0$ does not imply $f$ increasing in a neighbourhood of $x_0$: Take $f(x)=x^2\sin(4/x) +x$ and $x_0=0$.

Comment: @Jose27 True. I was thinking about polynomials. =)

Comment: @Jose27 It is sufficient that $f'$ is continuous at $x=x_0$ to assert $f$ is increasing in a nbhd of $x_0$, is it not?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Yes, because then $f'>0$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, that was my thought.

Comment: I was going to edit a couple of typos, but then I did not know how you intended to state the math around one of them. Hence, I will just leave a comment pointing them out. The theorem statement should say "Then $f$ is Lipschitz...", and in the last line you may have intended either "for all $n\ge N$" or you may have intended to use capital $N$ in the display inequality.

Comment: @user1 I meant capital $N$. I copied and pasted from the previous line.

Comment: I'd like it too, had I posted it! +

Comment: @Jose27 wouldn't you have to have a separate case where you define f(0) to be equal to 0 in order for that particular f to be differentiable at 0?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x)=a_n x^n+\cdots+a_0$ a polynomial with $n\geq 2$. You should show that there's no $k$ such that
$$|P(x)-P(y)|\leq k|x-y|\quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb R.$$

Comment: so where do I begin to show there is no k?

Comment: Suppose that there's a  (*fixed*) $k$ then taking the limit of $\frac{|P(x)-P(y)|}{|x-y|}$ when $x\to y$ and by choosing a suitable $x$ you find a contradiction.

Comment: why are you taking the limit of that?

Comment: By taking the limit you find the derivative of the polynomial and you find a simple expression that you allowed to find a contradiction.

Comment: I have not yet gone over using derivative in my class, is there another approach to this?

Comment: Yes there's, do you know how factor $x^k-y^k=(x-y)(x^{k-1}+...)$? if yes then do it and simplify by $|x-y|$ and fix $y$ and take $x$ large enough to find a contradiction.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by fix y and take x large enough?

Comment: If you choose for $x$ a big value (big number) the expression on the left will be greater than $k$ which's a contradiction.

Comment: So I have x^k−y^k=(x−y)(x^k−1+y^k-1) < (x-y) where k = 1. And taking x large will make the left hand side larger than the right hand side which contradicts the definition of Lip. Cont.?

Comment: That's exact but be careful the  factorisation is $$x^k-y^k=(x-y)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+x^{k-3}y^2+\cdots+xy^{k-2}+y^{k-1})$$

Answer (score 1):

Intuition first: For large values of $x\in \mathbb R$, a polynomial of degree $n$ behaves much like $f(x)=x^n$ does. The latter, $n\ge 2$, is not Lipschitz.

To turn this intuition into a proof, you might first want to convince yourself of the validity of the two claims, and how that will prove what you are looking for.

So:

1) Campare $|P(x)-P(y)|$ to $|x^d-y^d|$ in a sensible way. 
2) Prove that $f(x)=x^d$, when  $d\ge 2$, is not Lipschitz. 
3) Use a suitable inequality you found in step 1 to conclude $P(x)$ is also not Lipschitz.